# How do I use a variable as a regex modifier in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, dynamic, case-sensitive, modifier

I'm writing an abstraction function that will ask the user a given question and validate the answer based on a given regular expression. The question is repeated until the answer matches the validation regexp.

However, I also want the client to be able to specify whether the answer must match case-sensitively or not.

So something like this:

```
sub ask {
    my ($prompt, $validationRe, $caseSensitive) = @_;
    my $modifier = ($caseSensitive) ? "" : "i";
    my $ans;
    my $isValid;

    do {
        print $prompt;
        $ans = <>;
        chomp($ans);

        # What I want to do that doesn't work:
        # $isValid = $ans =~ /$validationRe/$modifier;

        # What I have to do:
        $isValid = ($caseSensitive) ?
            ($ans =~ /$validationRe/) :
            ($ans =~ /$validationRe/i);

    } while (!$isValid);

    return $ans;
}
```

Upshot: is there a way to dynamically specify a regular expression's modifiers?

Comment: or is there a better way to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Upshot: is there a way to dynamically specify a regular expression's modifiers?

From `perldoc perlre`:

> "(?adlupimsx-imsx)"
>   "(?^alupimsx)"
>       One or more embedded pattern-match modifiers, to be turned on (or
>       turned off, if preceded by "-") for the remainder of the pattern or
>       the remainder of the enclosing pattern group (if any).
>
> This is particularly useful for dynamic patterns, such as those read
>       in from a configuration file, taken from an argument, or specified in
>       a table somewhere. Consider the case where some patterns want to be
>       case-sensitive and some do not: The case-insensitive ones merely need
>       to include "(?i)" at the front of the pattern.

Which gives you something along the lines of

```
$isValid = $ans =~ m/(?$modifier)$validationRe/;
```

Just be sure to take the appropriate security precautions when accepting user input in this way.

Answer (score 4):

You might also like the `qr` operator which [quotes its STRING as a regular expression](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators).

```
my $rex = qr/(?$mod)$pattern/;
$isValid = <STDIN> =~ $rex;
```

Comment: The PITA about this one is it excludes `g` >_<

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of your `$caseSensitive` parameter, as it will be useless in many cases. Instead, users of that function can encode the necessary information directly in the `$validationRe` regex.

When you create a regex object like `qr/foo/`, then the pattern is at that point compiled into instructions for the regex engine. If you stringify a regex object, you'll get a string that when interpolated back into a regex will have exactly the same behaviour as the original regex object. Most importantly, this means that all flags provided or omitted from the regex object literal will be preserved and can't be overridden! This is by design, so that a regex object will continue to behave identical no matter what context it is used in.

That's a bit dry, so let's use an example. Here is a `match` function that tries to apply a couple similar regexes to a list of strings. Which one will match?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

# This sub takes a string to match on, a regex, and a case insensitive marker.
# The regex will be recompiled to anchor at the start and end of the string.
sub match {
    my ($str, $re, $i) = @_;
    return $str =~ /\A$re\z/i if $i;
    return $str =~ /\A$re\z/;
}

my @words = qw/foo FOO foO/;
my $real_regex = qr/foo/;
my $fake_regex = 'foo';

for my $re ($fake_regex, $real_regex) {
    for my $i (0, 1) {
        for my $word (@words) {
            my $match = 0+ match($word, $re, $i);
            my $output = qq("$word" =~ /$re/);
            $output .= "i" if $i;
            say "$output\t-->" . uc($match ? "match" : "fail");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
"foo" =~ /foo/  -->MATCH
"FOO" =~ /foo/  -->FAIL
"foO" =~ /foo/  -->FAIL
"foo" =~ /foo/i -->MATCH
"FOO" =~ /foo/i -->MATCH
"foO" =~ /foo/i -->MATCH
"foo" =~ /(?^:foo)/     -->MATCH
"FOO" =~ /(?^:foo)/     -->FAIL
"foO" =~ /(?^:foo)/     -->FAIL
"foo" =~ /(?^:foo)/i    -->MATCH
"FOO" =~ /(?^:foo)/i    -->FAIL
"foO" =~ /(?^:foo)/i    -->FAIL
```

First, we should notice that the string representation of regex objects has this weird `(?^:...)` form. In a non-capturing group `(?: ... )`, modifiers for the pattern inside the group can be added or removed between the question mark and colon, while the `^` indicates the default set of flags.

Now when we look at the fake regex that's actually just a string being interpolated, we can see that the addition of the `/i` flag makes a difference as expected. But when we use a real regex object, it doesn't change anything: The outside `/i` cannot override the `(?^: ... )` flags.

It is probably best to assume that all regexes already are regex objects and should not be interfered with. If you load the regex patterns from a file, you should require the regexes to use the `(?: ... )` syntax to apply flages (e.g. `(?^i:foo)` as an equivalent to `qr/foo/i`). E.g. loading one regex per line from a file handle could look like:

```
my @regexes;
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    push @regexes, qr/$_/;  # will die here on regex syntax errors
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `eval` function. The below code will work:

```
sub ask {
    my ($prompt, $validationRe, $caseSensitive) = @_;
    my $modifier = ($caseSensitive) ? "" : "i";
    my $ans;
    my $isValid;

    do {
        print $prompt;
        $ans = <>;
        chomp($ans);

        # What I want to do that doesn't work:
        # $isValid = $ans =~ /$validationRe/$modifier;

        $isValid = eval "$ans =~ /$validationRe/$modifier";

        # What I have to do:
        #$isValid = ($caseSensitive) ?
        #    ($ans =~ /$validationRe/) :
        #    ($ans =~ /$validationRe/i);

    } while (!$isValid);

    return $ans;
}
```

Comment: Hi, before flagging it down, can anyone please explain what is wrong with this code ??

`Test:
$ans = "ABCDEF";
$modifier = "i";
$validationRe = "cD";
$isValid = eval "$ans =~ /$validationRe/$modifier";
print $isValid;

result:
1`

Comment: This code uses `eval` in it's dangerous form. It is terrifyingly easy to break thus code and even do dangerous stuff (consider what happens with `$validationRe = '/; print "You have been pwned\n"; exit -1; #'` or `$ans = 'die "This code is broken!"; #'`). Because you even interpolate `$ans`, there are very few cases where this will actually work at all. Have you even tested this code?

Comment: Yes amon i have tested this code. you can see sample in my first comment. If you try to play without proper validation anything can happen. User was looking for a way to read modifier from variable, i just suggested one way.

Comment: This answer is correct.  Good job @Amit. People need to stop downvoting code because of imaginary and paranoid security concerns.  $eval$ is powerful, useful, and in perl for a reason.  It's not the question-answer's responsibility to imagine every kind of abuse and injection.  If so, the only correct answer to all programming questions is: "# disconnect from internet, shut off computer, get new job, you may one day be pwned".